# Differences between software testing processes and techniques?

Tags: testing, unit-testing, sdlc

I get confused between these terms. For example, should unit testing be listed as a software testing process or technique? I think unit testing is a software testing technique. And how about Test driven development? Can you give me some examples for software testing processes and techniques?

In my opinion, software testing process is a part of the software development life cycle. For example, if we use V-Model, the software testing process will be System test, Acceptance test, Integration Test.

Answer (score 3):

A process is a series of actions or operations leading towards a particular result.  A technique is a practical method, skill, or art applied to a particular task.

Unit testing is both a process and a set of techniques.  You employ the process to achieve your particular aim, which is to obtain a level of confidence that the software works as it should.  But you apply a set of techniques to execute that process, which are the skills you developed to implement your unit tests.

Comment: base on your answer, should I understand that the Test driven development is a software testing technique? And if we have unit testing, system testing, acceptance testing... Can we understand them as a series of testing processes? Thank you.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?  Sure, you can call them testing processes.  You can also call them techniques.  I don't think the distinction really matters all that much.